# Replace Windows Directory Path using -replace that has backslashes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to treat the blackslashs as not being special to regular expressions?

```
[string]$users = "C:\Users\dude\"

[string]$path  = "C:\Users\dude\project1\project2"

$i2 = $path -replace $users, ".\"
```

Message:

```
The regular expression pattern C:\Users\dude\ is not valid.
char:2
+     $i2 = $item -replace "$users", ""
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Users\dude:String) [], 
RuntimeException
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid of using regex if you don't need to search something special by regex patterns:

```
cls
$users = "C:\Users\dude\"
$path  = "C:\Users\dude\project1\project2"

$i2 = $path.Replace($users, ".\")
$i2

# .\project1\project2
```

By the way, if **dude** - is your current user, you can use even simpler code:

```
cls
$path  = "C:\Users\dude\project1\project2"

$i2 = $path.Replace($HOME, ".")
$i2

# .\project1\project2
```

Comment: `.Replace()` works well with the specific inputs, but note that - unlike the `-replace` operator - it is case-_sensitive_, _invariably_ so in Windows PowerShell, and _by default_ in PowerShell (Core) 7+ (there you can use `'FOO'.Replace('f', 'b', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')`). Also not a concern in the specific use case, but worth mentioning: you cannot _anchor_ the substring matching with `.Replace()`, e.g. you cannot stipulate that matches must be at the _start_ of a string, which may be necessary when you're dealing with _relative_ paths.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. The larger point is that the _readership_ may not know, and while my comment now hopefully clarifies the general limitations of the `.Replace()` approach, it is always preferable to have such information _as part of the answer_, not least because comments tend to be overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69664338/45375) answers your question as asked.

Taking a step back: Your task involves removing the *verbatim prefix* stored in `$users` from the path stored in `$path`, so you can simply do:

```sh
'.\' + $path.Substring($users.Length)  # -> '.\project1\project2'
```

In cases where you do need to use a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and you want *prefix* matching (matching from the *start* of the input string), it is generally advisable to *anchor* the pattern at the start of the string (`^`) (even though in this particular case there's no risk of false positives; the anchoring also effectively prevents attempts to find *multiple* matches):

```sh
$path -replace ('^' + [regex]::Escape($users)), '.\'
```

Answer (score 0):

By escaping them:

```
$path = "C:\Users\dude\project1\project2"
$users = "C:\Users\dude\"
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($users)

$i2 = $path -replace $pattern, ".\"
```

`[regex]::Escape` will automatically escape any potential meta-character with a preceding `\`:

```
PS ~> [regex]::Escape("C:\Users\dude")
C:\\Users\\dude
```